# MySQL-delete function won't work inside stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-delete

```
DELIMITER //
drop procedure if exists mzeng.SP_Update_MG_mappingTable//
create procedure mzeng.SP_Update_MG_mappingTable(TerminalName varchar(55), 
TableName varchar(55))
begin
set @t=concat('INSERT INTO mzeng. 
t_item_name_major_group_mapping_',TableName,'(title, majorgroup)
select  distinct mi.title, mmi.majorgroup from ',TerminalName,'.menu_items 
mi  left join ',TerminalName,'.micros_menu_items mmi on 
mi.micros_menu_item_id = mmi.id
where mi.title not in( select distinct title from mzeng. 
t_item_name_major_group_mapping_',TableName,');

DELETE from mzeng.t_item_name_major_group_mapping_',TableName,' where 
title='';');

prepare stmt1 from @t;
execute stmt1;
deallocate prepare stmt1;

end//
delimiter ;
```

The procedure worked if i dont include the delete function inside the variable.
However, I need it to work for efficiency's sake.

Here is the error message

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'DELETE from
>   mzeng.t_item_name_major_group_mapping_jfkt2 where title=' at line
>   6 0.031 sec.

The delete function absolutely work if i use it outside of the procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html):

> Statement names are not case sensitive. `preparable_stmt` is either a string literal or a user variable that contains the text of the SQL statement. *The text must represent a single statement, not multiple statements*.